# How to add a remember me function in login?

Tags: php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$uname = $_POST['uname'];

$pw = $_POST['pw'];

    require_once('db.php');

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users_table 
                WHERE username="'.mysql_escape_string($uname).'" AND password="'.mysql_escape_string(md5($pw)).'"
            LIMIT 0, 1
    ';
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);   
    $count = mysql_num_rows($qry);

    if($count > 0) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pw;
        header('Location: products_list.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?error=1');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use setcookie() function to set the cookie and then retrieve it when user acess the login restricted pages

[setcookie description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using the Cookie, it runs amazingly perfect...
Only thing you need to do is just add encoding in cookies for security...

```
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {

$uname = $_POST['uname'];

$pw = $_POST['pw'];

require_once('db.php');

//Checking whether the cookies are set or not
if(!empty($_COOKIES['Last_Login_UserID']) && !empty($_COOKIES['Last_Login_Password'])){
    if($_COOKIES['Last_Login_UserID']==$uname && $_COOKIES['Last_Login_Password']==$pw){
        //Cookies are perfect give access
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pw;
         header('Location: products_list.php');
    }else{
        //Cookies cookies are wrong
        login_check($uname,$pw);
    }

}else{
    //Cookies are not set so check the database
    login_check($uname,$pw);
}
//Function to check the login
function login_check($uname,$pw){
     $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username="'.mysql_escape_string($uname).'" AND password="'.mysql_escape_string(md5($pw)).'" LIMIT 0, 1 ;';
$qry = mysql_query($sql);   
$count = mysql_num_rows($qry);

    if($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pw;
        if(!empty($_POST['remember_me']) && $_POST['remember_me']==true){
            setcookie('Last_Login_UserID',$_SESSION['username'],(60*60*24),"/");
            setcookie('Last_Login_Password',$_SESSION['password'],(60*60*24),"/");
        }
        header('Location: products_list.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?error=1');
    }
}}
```

Comment: i am new in php actually so how did you came up with this? ($_COOKIES['Last_Login_UserID']) && !empty($_COOKIES['Last_Login_Password']

Comment: just see in the function login_check, where if remember_me is set and value is true, code sets cookies and remember's that user

Comment: i copied and pasted your codes and i was not directed to the products_list.php file

Comment: have you made remember_me input checkbox in your form?

Comment: this code is for understanding the concept of remember me functionality, many changes may be needed

Comment: i am having a hard time figuring it out TBH but thanks anyway :)